# how to get the unique id in firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

ive had a lot of trouble with firebase arrays, im now using push

I have this

[image]

I want to pull all the users down so I do this:

```
export const pullFromFirebase = () => {
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/users/")
    .once("value")
    .then(snapshot => {
      var users = [];
      snapshot.forEach(user => {
        users.push(user.val());
      });
      return users;
    });
};
```

this is fine

however, I now need the unique id `-LI7d_i_BmrXktzMoe4p` that firebase generated for me so that I can access this record (i.e. for updating and deleting) how do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this part:

```
snapshot.forEach(user => {
  users.push(user.val());
});
```

To instead be:

```
let usersObj = snapshot.val()
for (var user_id in usersObj) {
  users.push(Object.assign(usersObj[user_id], {
    user_id: user_id,
  });
});
```

That way, instead of each element in the `users` array only having email, name and username fields, it has user_id as well.

Comment: oh yeh of course, nice!
but im gonna use spread:
`for (var user_id in usersObj) {
        users.push({ ...usersObj[user_id], id: user_id });
      }`

Comment: actually I have another problem. when i do the initial push it pushes the data to firebase but without the id, the id is only added to firebase after a refresh, how can I add the auto generated as an id key field immediately ?

Comment: @donut I'm not sure I'm following. The ID is only added to firebase after a refresh of what?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the key of the snapshot with the key property: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key

So you could change your code to this:

```
export const pullFromFirebase = () => {
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/users/")
    .once("value")
    .then(snapshot => {
      var users = [];
      snapshot.forEach(user => {
        let userObj = user.val();
        userObj.id= user.key;
        users.push(userObj);
      });
      return users;
    });
};
```